# basic-ftp moduleHas anyone managed to use webpack or Parcel with

Tags: javascript, windows, webpack, parceljs

I have tried using webpack 5 and Parcel to build the new .js files.
The javascript file before conversion works fine with node in the command prompt but I cannot get it to work in Windows (11). I am using the latest basic-ftp 5.0.4.

The error I get in the browser using Webpack or Parcel is

```
Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type 
Function
at promisify (util.js:614:11)
at 5u8Fu.c4216f9df743e6cc (Client.js:17:38)
at newRequire (index.47c005a7.js:71:24)
at localRequire (index.47c005a7.js:84:35)
at 2uKas.b1c576accb3ceae3 (index.js:21:14)
at newRequire (index.47c005a7.js:71:24)
at localRequire (index.47c005a7.js:84:35)
at 8Duvb.44a9388bb99fc836 (index1.js:7:16)
at newRequire (index.47c005a7.js:71:24)
at index.47c005a7.js:122:5
```

The src\index.html file contents are

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>My First Parcel App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script type="module" src="index1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</body>
</html>

The src\index1.js File I use is
```

`    // src/index1.js
// works with node index1.js

```
console.log("Starting");
// see https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp
const Client = require("basic-ftp")
//import * as Client from "basic-ftp"

//console.log(Client);
example();

async function example() {
const client = new Client.Client()
client.ftp.verbose = true
try {
await client.access({
host: "somehost",
user: "username",
password: "password",
secure: false
})
console.log(await client.list())
//await client.uploadFrom("README.md", "README_FTP.md")
//await client.downloadTo("README_COPY.md", README_FTP.md")
}
catch(err) {
console.log(err) 
}
client.close()
}

//import ftp from "basic-ftp";
console.log("Finished!");
```

`

```
My package.json is as follows:

{
"name": "parcel-demo",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"source": "src/index.html",
"scripts": {
"start": "parcel",
"build": "parcel build"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"buffer": "^6.0.3",
"node": "^21.2.0",
"parcel": "^2.10.3"
},
"dependencies": {
"basic-ftp": "^5.0.4"
}
}
```

'
My npm list is as follows:

```
+-- basic-ftp@5.0.4
+-- buffer@6.0.3
+-- node-bin-setup@1.1.3 extraneous
+-- node@21.2.0
`-- parcel@2.10.3
```

The index1.js and index.html are located in a src directory
To compile in Parcel at the command prompt type
npx parcel src/index.html --open

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My question is how to use https://github.com/patrickjuchli/basic-ftp on a web application.  I am new to this but have been at it for days and tried various node.js libraries to no avail.  My research showed that i would need to use Webpack or Parcel to package the javascript file.  The original question is the details from packaging with Parcel from parcel.org.

Comment: I have included the index.html contents and the command to compile in Parcel in the original question